# Is it safe to ride a bike with your macbook pro in sleep mode?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

I have the current mac book pro. Is it safe to ball around with it in sleep mode or could you damage the disk?

Comment: Depends on your biking skill and everyone else's driving :/

Comment: Are MacBook Airs the only ones with SSDs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is as safe as if it would be if it would be shut down or in hibernation. It depends on your cycling skills. :)